# How to display 3 decimal points without round up?

Tags: java, android, decimal, bigdecimal, number-formatting

I am making an app which need to display 3 decimal points i achieve this by 
    NumberDecimal but the issue is if 4th digit is >5 then 3rd digit
    automatically increase. I want to show exact figure for ex :

```
Result           : 100.2356 
Output           : 100.236  // Applying NumberDecimal
```

**Need this output : 100.235 // I need this output**

```
This is my function :
public String setdecimal(float a) 
{
   NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
   return formatter.format(a);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [RoundingMode.FLOOR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html):

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
```

Depending on how you want to handle negative numbers, you could also use `RoundingMode.DOWN`, which rounds towards zero.

Comment: its says without round-up

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to truncate the digits after the points without round up the value.

```
public static String getThreeDigitDisplayValueFromFloat(float value) {

    String price = new DecimalFormat("##.###").format(value);
    return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.3f", Float.parseFloat(price));
}
```